# shadow effect around image instead of image border

Tags: css, image

The photo below probably makes the problem obvious but basically, the `shadow effect` is around the `border` of the `image container` instead of the `image` itself which is not what I want. While keeping `object-fit: contain` is there a solution to this?

```
img {
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    height: calc(100% - 5px);
    object-fit: contain;

    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #0ff;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```css
    filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px 4px #4444dd);
```